# Booting Batocera .img Using Grub

Tags: boot, debian, grub, bootloader

Objective : Run Batorcera from an .img created with dd from a working install on a USB.  btc.img is a stored file on my computer and I would like to start up the OS using Grub.

I have tried these two Grub entries and both yield the same errors.

```
error: unknown filesystem.
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Here are the Grub menuentries.

```
menuentry "btc.img" {
  insmod ext2
  set isofile="/home/lex/share/isos/btc.img"
  loopback loop (hd0,msdos5)$isofile
  linux (loop)/vmlinuz label=BATOCERA console=tty3 quiet loglevel=0 vt.global_cursor_default=0 mitigations=off
  initrd (loop)/initrd.img
}


menuentry "btc.img" {
  insmod ext2
  set isofile="/home/lex/share/isos/btc.img"
  loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
  linux (loop)/boot/linux label=BATOCERA console=tty3 quiet loglevel=0 vt.global_cursor_default=0 mitigations=off
  initrd (loop)/boot/initrd.gz
}
```

Collected information :

fdisk -l  btc.img

```
Disk btc.img: 14.65 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1CD01666-ACAC-44F8-8AD2-CE446E954FE2

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
btc.img1         34 14680097 14680064    7G Microsoft basic data
btc.img2   14680098 30719966 16039869  7.6G Linux filesystem
```

kpartx -l batocera.img

```
loop0p1 : 0 14680064 /dev/loop0 34
loop0p2 : 0 16039869 /dev/loop0 14680098
```

Here is a photo of what Grub thinks the files system is.
https://mo-de.net/d/grub.JPG

parted /home/lex/share/isos/btc.img UNIT b print

```
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/lex/share/isos/btc.img: 15728640000B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start        End           Size         File system  Name      Flags
 1      17408B       7516210175B   7516192768B  fat32        vfat      legacy_boot, msftdata
 2      7516210176B  15728623103B  8212412928B  ext4         userdata
```